# How to deploy a Cassandra cluster on two ec2 machines?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra

It's a known fact that it is not possible to create a cluster in a single machine by changing ports. The workaround is to add virtual Ethernet devices to our machine and use these to configure the cluster.

I want to deploy a cluster of , let's say 6 nodes, on two ec2 instances. That means, 3 nodes on each machine.   Is it possible? What should be the seed nodes address, if it's possible?
Is it a good idea for production?

Comment: Interesting. Does this approach have an advantage over Vnodes?

Comment: We are looking for such possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Datastax AMI on AWS.  Datastax Enterprise is a suitable solution for production.

I am not sure about your cluster, because each node need its own config files and it is default. I have no idea how to change it.

There are simple instructions [here](http://datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/install/installAMI.html). When you configure instances settings, you have to write advanced settings for cluster, like `--clustername yourCluster --totalnodes 6 --version community` etc. You also can install Cassandra manually by installing latest version java and cassandra.

You can build cluster by modifying `/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml` (Ubuntu 12.04) fields like `cluster_name`, `seeds`, `listener_address`, `rpc_broadcast` and `token`. `Cluster_name` have to be same for whole cluster. Seed is master node, which IP you should add for every node. I am confused about tokens